# Loop through a CSV file

Tags: php, csv

How can i do a foreach with a CSV file.

Suppose i have fopen a csv file which looks like so ---

```
Array
(
    [0] => Category ID
    [1] => Category
    [2] => Country
    [3] => Original price
    [4] => Reduce price
)
Array
(
    [0] => 11
    [1] => Phone cases
    [2] => Denmark
    [3] => 90,99
    [4] => 120
)
Array
(
    [0] => 13
    [1] => Shoes
    [2] => Denmark
    [3] => 180,99
    [4] => 200
)
```

So how can i loop through all the data's in store them in a array.

I have tried like so, but it does not work.

```
      $all_data = array();
        foreach ($result as $key => $obj) {

            $doc = array();
            $doc['id'] = $obj[$key];
            $doc['category'] = $obj[$key];
            $doc['country'] = $obj[$key];
            $doc['original_price'] = $obj[$key];
            $doc['reduce_price'] = $obj[$key];
           // array push all documents into $all_data
            $all_data [] = $doc;
        }
```

Anyone knows how i can loop through those data!

Comment: well you are using the $key variable incorrectly. the $key would be the key value from $results not the $object.

Comment: Why are you trying to take it out of one variable and add it to another?

Comment: @CameronSpanos i just want to be able to search from the csv file, so i think if i sort all the documents in one array it will be easier for for a handle them how i want to be !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just using the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.fgetcsv.php) :

```
if (($handle = fopen("yourfile.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $all_data = array();

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        if($i==0){ continue; $i=1; }
        // Remove the first iteration as it's not "real" datas

        $all_data[] = array(
            'id' => $data[0],
            'category' => $data[1],
            'country' => $data[2],
            'original_price' => $data[3],
            'reduce_price' => $data[4],
        );
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

It must achieve what you want. It's always better using the built-in functions. If you can't use this one, let me know.

---

**EDIT :**

As @Blag said :

> you can use to file_get_contents() and str_getcsv()

But this is a different approach that'll load the full file in a string (file_get_contents) and parse the string in the second time (str_getcsv).

Comment: thanks for your ans but in your answer where the **$obj** is defined !

Comment: you can use to [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [str_getcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)

Comment: @ChristoferHansen typo in the wile : `while (($obj = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {`

Comment: @RaphaëlVigée put your php comment on the line above to get rip-off the scroll ;)

Comment: Haha you're welcome ! Don't forget to mark the question as solved !

Comment: @RaphaëlVigée I have improve a bit your code to don't use var for nothing

Comment: yes, I change it twice again XD (I'm on many subject and make some typo)

Comment: Haha okay, make a clean edit, I'll see if it's relevant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94992/discussion-between-blag-and-raphael-vigee).

Comment: Please update documentation link from French to English. I cannot do this since it's a too small changeset. Also, please assign `$i` before using it. It's not a good practice.

Answer (score -1):

This should give you an idea of how to proceed :

```
$objsOut=array();
 foreach ($result as $key => $obj) {
    $objOut = array(
        'id'=>$obj[0]
    );
    $objsOut[]=$objOut;
}
```